# Why is a pod in my GKE cluster receiving repeated requests to the root path of web server?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a web server on port 8080. I have a Ingress object made by Google routing external traffic to a service that points to the pod.

My logs are littered with a request from 10.4.0.1:(some rotating large port) at "/" and it is eating CPU cycles as my web server generates the HTML to respond. It seems like a health check probe.

My pod has the following probe configs on my deployment:

```
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: "/status"
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: "/status"
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds:
```

Though it looks like I may have missed something in the configuration.

I've used `tcpdump -X port 8080` to examine the traffic. It looks as though the same source (10.4.0.1) are conducting the status check (at "/status") and a mysterious check at root ("/") back to back. It seems as though it is the kubelet but I haven't found proof. The pod IP range is `10.4.0.0/14`. It also seems as though the new configuration worked but the default probe config wasn't removed.

After applying changes to the deployment, do I need to purge and restart the service? Ingress? Node? I'm new to Kubernetes and am lost.

Help of any kind is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is that port exposed via a LoadBalancer service?

Comment: What is the RPS value of the requests to the "/"? What is CPU consumption caused by those requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the issue I had to change the configuration on a VM Instance Health Check that is part of Google's Compute Engine API. Setting the path to "/status" seemed to do the trick. So in short there is a health check from both kubernetes and GCE.